# How to update an org parent header's checkboxes count automatically?

Tags: org-mode

I want to update an `org-mode` checkbox total count automatically.  For example, if I have this:

```
* TODO Parent task [0/2] ;; I have 0/2
** TODO Children1
** TODO Children2
```

And then, if I add a third task, the parent task checkbox should be changed automatically to 3.

```
* TODO Parent task [0/3] ;; now I have 0/3
** TODO Children1
** TODO Children2
** TODO New
```

The same way, if I remove any task, the parent checkbox should immediately change to [0/2].

How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use @wasamasa's solution for adding new headers.

There are no default org commands for removing a heading and updating the todo count at the same time. It is possible to update all todo counts in the document by calling function `org-update-statistics-cookies` with the universal argument (`C-u C-c #`).

There many ways to remove a heading, so not all of them can not trigger the todo update. You have to create a function for it and include the non-interactive function `org-update-parent-todo-statistics` to the end of it. The alternative is to modify an existing command.

The following shows how to modify a command from the [worf](https://github.com/abo-abo/worf) package:

```
;; define an advice
(defadvice worf-delete-subtree (after my-org-update-parent-todo ())
  (org-update-parent-todo-statistics))
;; activate all advices to this function
(ad-activate 'worf-delete-subtree)
```

Execute both sexps, place the cursor at the asterisks of the header you want to remove, and press `C-d`. The line is deleted and the todo count is updated.

Answer (score 6):

Use `M-S-RET` to add the TODO item *and* update the above item's count.